# How optimize css and/or other resource modification in web application in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, html, css, web-applications, intellij-idea

I have a Web application with webapp folder, that contains css/style.css file. I want to edit this file and see what is happening in user interface. To do this I must follow 2 ways:

```
1. Edit css/style.css file and redeploy whole application.
2. Go to applciation folder in web container, edit css/style.css in it (this time I can see all changes simultaneously), copy it to project structure. Redeploy again to see that all changes have applied.
```

So I want to edit static resource files (not only css, but images, plaint html etc.) and do not copy they manually from project to webcontainer folder and do not restart web container on each changes. Is it possible with Intellij Idea?

Comment: (I'm not sure if I understand you needs...)
Use Chrome developer tools, You can edit Css/Html on live and see what is the result.

Comment: I can. But Browser could not save my style changes in the original css file.

Comment: well, after you happy with your changes just copy paste to the original files...

Answer (score 1):

Install and enable the Live Edit [plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/liveedit-plugin-features-in-detail/#more-4098). But only Chrome is supported.